# Exclude arrow functions from transpiling

Tags: javascript, babeljs, arrow-functions, babel-preset-env

I'm trying to stop Babel from transpiling arrow functions using 
`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
        {
          "exclude": [
            "transform-regenerator",
            "transform-async-to-generator",
            "transform-arrow-functions"
          ]
        }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

The `"transform-arrow-functions"` does not compile and cause an error.
But it is specified here, included in preset-env:
https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/data/plugin-features.js

Comment: Looks like you're stuck on Babel 6.x?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Babel 6 it has to be:

```
exclude: [
  "transform-regenerator",
  "transform-async-to-generator",
  "transform-es2015-arrow-functions"
]
```

So it's just the term *es2015-* which is missing in your configuration. The [link](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/data/plugin-features.js) you are referring to targets the `master` branch; which stays for Babel 7 currently.